# Hdfs Data Balance on Cluster

Tags: bigdata, apache-hadoop

Im new to Big Data, so please just dont blast me.

Can you explain me why HDFS works
best when the file blocks are evenly spread across the cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

If the data is not evenly distributed, there are several data blocks that take substantially longer to perform certain queries which undermines the performance of the whole [Hadoop](https://databasecamp.de/en/data/hadoop-explained) cluster and can even lead to errors.

Since [HDFS](https://databasecamp.de/en/data/apache-hdfs) is built to guarantee high fault tolerance, it needs to ensure balanced file blocks to minimize the risk of failure.